# Getting "An action can only be invoked as a 'POST' request" when I am trying to call outlook restful api

Tags: c#, rest, office365, outlook-api

Currently working with the outlook api, even tough I usually work with the outlook library acquired via Nuget; I have reached a limitation where I am not able to accept event invitations.  So I proceeded in making a a restful call out to the the outlook api.  However, when I am making the call I am getting the following message {"error":{"code":"InvalidMethod","message":"An action can only be invoked as a 'POST' request."}} when executing the call.

**Bad Code**

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
                var testAccept = ExecuteClientCall.AcceptEvent().Result; 
        }

 public static async Task<bool> AcceptEvent()
        {
            AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(CrmPrototype.Helpers.AuthHelper.devTenant);
            try
            {
                var token = await GetTokenHelperAsync(authenticationContext, CrmPrototype.Helpers.AuthHelper.OutlookAuthenticationEndpoint);
                string requestUrl = "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/Users/***@nowwhere.com/events('AAQkAGZiNDQxZTVkLWQzZjEtNDdjNy04OTc4LTM4NmNjM2JiOTRjNAAQAFpV0CnWR0FIpWFYRtszPHU=')/accept";

                HttpClient hc = new HttpClient();
                hc.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

                var method = new HttpMethod("POST");

                var request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, requestUrl)
                {
                    Content = new StringContent("{SendResponse: true}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
                };

                HttpResponseMessage hrm = await hc.GetAsync(requestUrl);



                if (hrm.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string jsonresult = await hrm.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    var stophere = 0;

                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the reason is that you called

```
hc.GetAsync(requestUrl);
```

The doc said that this method:

```
Sends a GET request to the specified Uri as an asynchronous operation.
```

Try:

```
PostAsync(Uri, HttpContent)
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `request` contains an  `HttpRequestMessage` object that you have created, but your code presently doesn't do anything with it.

Try replacing the line

```
                HttpResponseMessage hrm = await hc.GetAsync(requestUrl);
```

(which, as pointed out by the other answer, makes a `GET` request), with

```
                HttpResponseMessage hrm = await hc.SendAsync(request);
```